# Canadian citizen applying for Green Card while in the US + side question

Tags: usa, immigration, canada, greencard

I am an American citizen. My girlfriend lives in Canada. I have been going over possibilities of trying to get her a green card legally, and one possibility has me a bit stuck.

A Canadian citizen may come over to the US for up to 6 months. During this time, if they apply for a Green Card, could the process be completed and the individual be granted a Green Card in those 6 months, or would that simply not be enough time?

The other question/option is for her to get an employment-based Green card. Would that be a much more viable option as opposed to coming over here staying and attempting to get one while over here?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you will marry her and petition her to immigrate as a spouse. The process to get a green card in the US is Adjustment of Status. It is not a problem that Adjustment of Status isn't completed within their period of stay, because once someone has Adjustment of Status (I-485) is filed, they can stay in the US for as long as it is pending regardless of whether they have status or not (and in fact cannot leave the US without Advance Parole, or they will abandon their Adjustment of Status).

(In fact, in her category, she doesn't even need to be in status at the time of applying for Adjustment of Status; she could have overstayed for years and still be eligible for Adjustment of Status. In some other categories, she might need to be in status at the time of applying for Adjustment of Status, but it is true in all categories that she doesn't need to maintain status while Adjustment of Status is pending, and going out of status while Adjustment of Status is pending won't affect the Adjustment of Status.)

Employment-based immigration requires being petitioned by a US company that will employ her after she immigrates. This usually requires the company to go through a complicated process, and companies generally don't go through the effort to petition people unless they are already working for the company in the US. Unless she has such an employer, employment-based immigration is not a viable option.

Comment: If she's in the US and stays 6 months, within the 6 months can she apply for a Green card? 
Is that form an I-140 form?

Comment: @Kyukiou: I-140 is the employment-based petition. A family-based petition would be I-130. The petition is not the same as applying for a green card. To get a green card, one must either do Adjustment of Status (I-485) inside the US, or Consular Processing abroad to get an immigrant visa. One cannot do Adjustment of Status or Consular Processing until a visa number is available for the category and priority date.

Comment: @Kyukiou: For the Immediate Relative category (spouse, parent, or unmarried under-21 child of a US citizen), visa numbers are always available, so I-130 can be filed with I-485. For other family-based categories, visa numbers are not immediately available currently. For employment-based categories, visa numbers are currently immediately available for EB1, EB2, and EB3 as long as she wasn't born in Mainland China, India, or the Philippines.

Comment: We can't possibly do the marriage route, it would simply take way too long and neither of us are wealthy enough for the costs involved.
Edit1: She is a Canadian born citizen.
Edit2: It is true that I would like to marry her as she for me. But, we would like to get married at our own pace when we both actually have money saved up. Currently, if we were both to do the marriage route for the green card, it would be another 10-15 years from now.

Comment: @Kyukiou: You mean you don't want to get married until 10-15 years from now? Or you can't spare less than $2000 until 10-15 years from now?

Comment: $2000.00 is a lot of money for someone like me. I currently live below poverty line, so yes, if I were to start saving now, it would take around 10-15 years to come up with the money.

Comment: Do you realize that adjustment of status for her would be >$1000?

Comment: To mkennedy, that doesn't sound too bad, still would take time though. 
But, what would be the most logical way to follow the 485 path.
Does she just come on over within the 6 month visa-free entry and then apply for adjustment at that exact moment, or is there something else I am overlooking?

Comment: @Kyukiou "is there something else I am overlooking?": She cannot apply for adjustment of status without a petition.  If you do not marry her, you cannot petition for her.  Assuming she has no family in the US who *can* petition for her, she would need to find an employer willing to petition for her, which is far easier said than done.  What kinds of jobs is she qualified for?

Comment: Thats a small problem. She has 7.5 years experience working as a supervisor at a Tim Horton's, 3 years college experience to which she dropped out as she couldn't afford it anymore. Was going to school for an RN. Our local newspapers has been running ads for CNA's 2+ years for both training and job openings and offers up to a $5,000.00 sign on bonus. I have attempted to contact one of the hospital H.R's and they are eager to meet her as well as allow her into the CNA training, but talks of sponsorships (greencard) leads me to a silent dead end.

Comment: @Kyukiou there's another option besides family or employer sponsorship that I overlooked: the green card lottery.  This option is unavailable, however, if she was born in Canada, Mexico, the UK, or any of several other countries.

Comment: I see then. I suppose the waiting game of 10-15 years is our only option.